# Wrong shadows with Cycles Renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shadows

I've tried to preview my final render, however I've noticed that the shadows are casted incorrectly. The problem isn't the positioning. Moving the lights doesn't affect shadows and only makes already illuminated areas brighter if the light source is near them. But even if I put the point light in front of the face, the shadows aren't modified at all.
I've tried strenghtening the light and changing its size, however the shadows are still wrong.

Is there any step I've missed? How can I fix this?

[image: Shadows are casted wrongly, just like on this screenshot]
[image: Seen from other perspective]

Comment: reduce the strength and move the lamp

Comment: @JacksonPro check the other pic I uploaded. The problem isn't the positioning. Moving the lights doesn't affect shadows and only makes already illuminated areas brighter if the light source is near them. But even if I put the point light in front of the face, the shadows aren't modified at all.

Comment: Try to make the light size smaller. If the object fall off the light radius it won't be affected.

Comment: @Carlo I tried that, placing the face into the light's radius but that didn't work. The shadows didn't change at all and already illuminated areas just got brighter.

Comment: Are you sure that those are shadows? Could you upload your file for inspection?

Comment: @Carlo I added a link for the file.

Comment: @MikhalHjadynkov access denied

Comment: @JacksonPro changed privacy settings, you should be able to access it.

Comment: @MikhalHjadynkov can you also place textures in separate folder and upload

Comment: @JacksonPro Link is updated.

Answer (score 2):

### Incomplete node setup

Normal maps need a conversion  before you feed them to the shaders. The black spots you are experiencing are not shadows, but an incorrect calculation of the surfaces normals.

A **Normal Map node** must be added between the texture and the shader.

As said in [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html):

> The Normal Map node generates a perturbed normal from an RGB normal
>   map image. This is usually chained with an Image Texture node in the
>   color input, to specify the normal map image.

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know I needed to do that to begin with, and it was indeed the problem. So then should I do this everytime when I import an object with a normal map?

Comment: For the common Normal maps, yes you should.